Number Theory Challenge: A broken elevator can only go up or down by the difference of two divisors of $n$
The problem statement:

A broken elevator can only be in odd floors and, if it is in the floor $n$, it can only go up or down by the difference of two divisors of $n$. Starting from any floor, can it arrive to the rest? (Except when it starts in floor $1$)

I believe that you can indeed get to any other floor.
However, after having tried the first cases, I haven't been able to spot any pattern.
Alternatively, i've tried the following:
$\textbf{Lemma 1: }\text{if }d\mid n \text{, then you can reach } d,\text{ from }n\text{. Note: } n-(n-d)=d$
From $n$ we can reach $2n-1$. Therefore
$\textbf{Lemma 2: }\text{starting from }n\text{, we can reach }2^m(n-1)+1\text{ for any }m$
I tried to prove that this sequence eventually has a term divisible by any $d$. However, this isn't true as when $n=3, d=7$, there is no such term in the sequence.
But the idea of finding a sequence starting from $n$ which eventually has a term divisible by any odd number might prove to be useful given $\textbf{lemma 1}$. This would prove our conjecture.
I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

@Peter, If the elevator is at $n=100$, then $10$ and $100$ are divisors of $n$, so the elevator can move up or down by $100-10=90$, and hence reach $10$ or $190$ in one move. Note however we are restricted to odd $n$, so this is a poor example.

Maybe it helps that it is sufficient to prove that we can reach every number $n$ with $3\mid n$

If $n$ is prime , we can only reach $2n-1$ , so it can be necessary to go over numbers much larger than the starting number $n$ , in particular if we find a long chain of primes generated by the iteration $2n-1$. However , I think such a chain must be finite , so your conjecture probably is still alive.

$2^m(n-1)+1$ is not prime for all $m$. If $p=2^m(n-1)+1$ is prime then $2^{m+p-1}(n-1)+1\equiv 2^m(n-1)+1\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }p)$

The following algorithm seems to generate all numbers: let $a_0$ be the floor in which you start and, for $n>0$, $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ if $a_{n-1}$ is prime or if all its divisors already appear in the sequence, otherwise let $a_n$ be the smallest divisor of $a_{n-1}$ that hasn't appeared in the sequence yet.

@Torrente If you could prove this , this would be a very elegant method !

What is the source of this problem?

"can only be in odd floors": I'm having trouble understanding this. Do you mean that it can only start from an odd floor?

@TonyK Thats how I took it. You can only start on odd floor, and since every divisor of an odd number is odd, you can only go to odd floors.

@Sil I got stuck in the elevator and came up with it

@QC_QAOA Yes, That's right

Are you only considering positive divisors and positive floors?

@Servaes Yes, when I thought about the problem I only considered positive floors and divisors. In fact, if negative divisors were allowed, the problem can be solved using the fact that you can go to 2n+1 and 2n-1 as somebody mentioned a while algo(they removed their answer)

If $n=p$ is prime then the only option is to go to floor $2p-1$. If this is again prime, there is again only one option. Chains of primes given by $p_{k+1}=2p_k-1$ are known as Cunningham chains of the second kind, and fairly long chains are known. I believe all such chains must be finite, but cannot find a reference at the moment. If there were an infinite chain, then it would not be possible to get to every floor from any floor.

I made a detailed answer, but found a mistake, so i deleted it. I'll put it back again if i find a solution to it. I believe it isn't possible to go from floor 11 to floor 121=11^2

@SimónFlavioIbañez $11\to 21\to 3\to 5\to 9\to 17\to 33\to 31\to 61\to 121$

I think I am confused/ If an elevator can only be on odd floors as in the statement of the problem, then how can it visit all the floors including the even ones. What am I missing here.

The question now has a complete answer, thank you to everyone who answered the bounty and particular thanks to @Aphelli for their simple yet direct answer. My original answer is kept below as reference, this answer is a combination of work to provide a full reference for an answer.
The structure of this proof is as follows:

Prove that you can reach floor $3$ from any floor
Prove you can reach any floor from floor $3$

Step 1
Let $n$ be the starting floor and consider $n$ modulo $3$.

If $n\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }3)$ then you can reach floor $3$.

If $n\equiv 2\ (\text{mod }3)$ then you can reach floor $2n-1\equiv 2\cdot 2-1=3\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }3)$ and can therefore reach floor $3$.

If $n\equiv 1\ (\text{mod }3)$ then we can use @Aphelli's proof: Write $n-1=2^rm$ with $r \ge 1$ and $m$ odd divisible by $3$. Then $m+2$ has an odd prime divisor $q \equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Thus $n-1+2^{r+1}$ is divisible by $q$. Let $t > q+r+1$ be a large integer. Then $2^{t(q-1)-(r+1)}(n-1)+2^{t(q-1)}$ is divisible by $q$. By Fermat’s little theorem, $q \mid 2^{t(q-1)-(r+1)}(n-1)+1$. Then we can reach floor $2q-1\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }3)$ and from there go to floor $3$.


Step 2
In this step we will show that you can reach any floor from floor $3$. To start our strong induction proof, note that we can reach any odd floor less than $13$ by manually checking. Now, we will proceed modulo $12$. Suppose we have reached every odd floor less than $12k+r$ where $r\in\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$ and $k\geq 1$ ($k=0$ is the base case). We will show that we can reach floor $12k+r$ from a strictly lower floor.

$r=1:\ 6k+1\to (6k+1)+(6k+1-1)=12k+1$

$r=3:\ 6k+3=3(2k+1)\to (6k+3)+(6k+3-3)=12k+3$

$r=5:\ 6k+3\to (6k+3)+(6k+3-1)=12k+5$

$r=7:\ 6k+5\to (6k+5)+(6k+5-1)=12k+9$
$=3(4k+3)\to (12k+9)-(3-1)=12k+7$

$r=9:\ 6k+5\to (6k+5)+(6k+5-1)=12k+9$

$r=11:\ 12k+9=3(4k+3)\to (12k+9)+(3-1)=12k+11$


We conclude we can reach any floor from floor $3$.

ORIGINAL ANSWER

I did not prove the question... but
I did manage to prove the question three ways, contingent on three different conjectures each way:  Artin's Conjecture, the 1st Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture, and an alternative conjecture (that I made up for this post). Unfortunately, Artin's Conjecture and the 1st Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture seem to both be extremely difficult and I cannot make progress on the alternative conjecture I created for this post but maybe someone else can.
The structure of this proof is as follows:

Prove that you can reach floor $3$ from any floor
Prove you can reach any floor from floor $3$

I'll give three versions for a proof of step one based on the three conjectures:
Step 1: Artin's Conjecture
Artin's Conjecture states that infinitely many primes have $2$ as a primitive root. Further, the ratio of primes with $2$ as a primitive root approaches some constant $C$ with $C$ about $0.37$. That is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{p:p\text{ is prime, }2\text{ is a primitive root of }p\text{, and }p\leq n\}|}{|\{p:p\text{ is prime and }p\leq n\}|}=C\approx 0.37$$
However, the following proof is dependent on the speed to which this converges. It is enough to say that for $n\geq 4400$ we have
$$\frac{|\{p:p\text{ is prime, }2\text{ is a primitive root of }p\text{, and }p\leq n\}|}{|\{p:p\text{ is prime and }p\leq n\}|}>0.1$$
We will use this 'fact' to show we can get below floor $4400$, and from there we can manually check that every floor can reach floor $3$.
Start at floor $n$ and let $p$ be the smallest prime factor of $n$. If $p$ is less than $4400$, we are done. If not, it is sufficient to show that we can get to a floor below $p$. Now, let $q$ be the smallest prime with $2$ properties

$q$ does not divide $p-1$
$2$ is a primitive root of $q$

By our assumption we know that $q$ must always exist. We will show that $q$ must be strictly less than $p$. First, note that $p$ is at least the $580$th primes. That is, if $\text{prime}(a)=p$ then $a\geq 580$. Second, by our assumption we know that at least $10\%$ of the primes smaller than $p$ have $2$ as a primitive root. Finally, $p-1$ is made of less than $5\%$ of the $a$ prime factors smaller than $p$ since since
$$2^{0.05a}\leq p-1<p<2 a\log(a)$$
which is not true for $a>100$. The first inequality comes from the fact that every prime is greater than or equal to $2$ and the last inequality comes from the prime number theorem. So at least $5\%$ of the prime factors less than $5$ satisfy both conditions on $q$. But this finishes this section of the proof! By our construction we know that there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$2^m(p-1)+1\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }q)$$
and so we can reach floor $q$. The final piece is to check that each prime less than $4400$ can reach floor $3$. We can check that the alternative conjecture (see Step 1: Alternative Conjecture) holds for each prime less than $4400$. This is indeed the case and there is a way to get to floor $3$ from each prime less than $4400$.
Step 1: 1st Hard-Littlewood Conjecture
We are concerned with this conjecture for what it says about Cunningham chains of the second kind. These are chains of primes of the form
$$p_m=2^m(p-1)+1$$
where $p_0=p$. Specifically, the conjecture says that the number of chains with length $k$ less than $N$ should be asymptotic to
$$\frac{N}{(\log(N))^k}\cdot 2^{k-1}\prod_{p>2}\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}\min(k,ord_p(2))}{(p-1)^k}$$
where the product is taken over all primes greater than $p$. Again, since this is only a conjecture we would need to bound the growth of this function. It is enough to say that for all $N\geq 8\times 10^8$ and all $k\geq 30$ we have that the number of Cunningham Chains of length $k$ that has a first member less than $N$ is strictly less than
$$\frac{10^k N}{(\log(N))^k}$$
Note here we have also simplified the product over the primes with the bound $10^k$. Again, we can manually check each prime less than $8\times 10^8$ (I didn't actually check this since this is conjectural anyways). Suppose we are starting on some floor $n$ with a smallest prime factor $p$ greater than $8\times 10^8$. Further suppose that the Cunningham Chain created by $p$ is of length less than $30$. Note that if $2p-1$ is not prime we are still fine. We know that there exists $m<30$ such that
$$2^m(p-1)+1$$
is not prime. Since it is not prime, it must have a prime factor $q$ less than or equal to
$$q\leq \sqrt{2^m(p-1)+1}<\sqrt{2^mp}\leq \sqrt{2^{29}p}$$
If we can show that this prime factor is less than $p$, then we are done. But this is simple, if this were not the case then
$$2^{29}p\geq p^2$$
$$8\times 10^8>536870912=2^{29}\geq p$$
which is false. Now, from our assumption we know that we can bound a possible chain of length $k$ with starting point $N$ with the formula
$$\frac{10^k N}{(\log(N))^k}<\frac{1}{2}$$
That is, if $\frac{10^k N}{(\log(N))^k}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, we are assured there are no Cunningham Chains of length $k$ that have a starting point less than $N$. Solving this for $k$ in terms of $N$ gives
$$k= \frac{\log(N)+\log(2)}{\log(\log(N))-\log(10)}$$
Putting $N=p+1$ into this formula, we repeat the same procedure we just used: if $k$ is the maximum length Cunningham Chain generated by a prime smaller than $p+1$, then we know that
$$k<\frac{\log(p+1)+\log(2)}{\log(\log(p+1))-\log(10)}$$
We also know that there exists $1\leq m\leq k$ such that
$$2^m(p-1)+1$$
is not prime. We need to show that the square root of this quantity is strictly less than $p$. But of course, we have a bound on $m$ in terms of $p$. This means we have to show
$$2^m(p-1)+1<2^mp\leq 2\hat{}\left[\frac{\log(p+1)+\log(2)}{\log(\log(p+1))-\log(10)}\right]p<p^2$$
$$2\hat{}\left[{\frac{\log(p+1)+\log(2)}{\log(\log(p+1))-\log(10)}}\right]<p$$
This is a simple analysis problem. We can show this is true for $p>8\times 10^8$. Why $8\times 10^8$? Well, I shoved a lot of bounds from the conjecture into
$$\frac{N}{(\log(N))^k}2^{k-1}\prod_{p>2}\frac{p^k-p^{k-1}\min(k,ord_p(2))}{(p-1)^k}<\frac{10^k N}{(\log(N))^k}$$
(specifically that $10^k$) and I would assume a proof of the 1st Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture could make a much tighter bound. Continuing, we may conclude that for primes larger than $8\times 10^8$ we have that at least one factor of $2^m(p-1)+1$ is smaller than $\sqrt{p}$. We conclude by induction that we can get lower than $8\times 10^8$.
Step 1: Alternative Conjecture
The alternative conjecture is that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the sequence $2^m\cdot 3k+1$ is eventually divisible by a prime of the form $3a+2$ (see Discussion below for my best attempt at proving this). Suppose you start on floor $n$. There are three cases based on the three residue classes modulo $3$ of $n$:
Case 1: If $n\equiv 0\ (\text{mod }3)$ then we are done.
Case 2: If $n\equiv 2\ (\text{mod }3)$, then we can reach floor
$$2n-1=2(3a+2)-1=6a+4-1=6a+3=3(2a+1)$$
and we are done.
Case 3: Suppose $n\equiv 1\ (\text{mod }3)$. If any prime factor of $n$ has the form $3a+2$ then go back to step $2$. If not, then by our assumption we know that eventually $2^m(n-1)+1$ has a prime factor of the form $3a+2$ since $n-1$ is divisible by $3$.
Step 2
In this step we will show that you can reach any floor from floor $3$. To start our strong induction proof, note that we can reach any odd floor less than $13$ by manually checking. Now, we will proceed modulo $12$. Suppose we have reached every odd floor less than $12k+r$ where $r\in\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$ and $k\geq 1$ ($k=0$ is the base case). We will show that we can reach floor $12k+r$ from a strictly lower floor.
$$r=1:\ 6k+1\to (6k+1)+(6k+1-1)=12k+1$$
$$r=3:\ 6k+3=3(2k+1)\to (6k+3)+(6k+3-3)=12k+3$$
$$r=5:\ 6k+3\to (6k+3)+(6k+3-1)=12k+5$$
$$r=7:\ 6k+5\to (6k+5)+(6k+5-1)=12k+9=3(4k+3)\to (12k+9)-(3-1)=12k+7$$
$$r=9:\ 6k+5\to (6k+5)+(6k+5-1)=12k+9$$
$$r=11:\ 6k+5\to (6k+5)+(6k+5-1)=12k+9$$
$$=3(4k+3)\to (12k+9)+(3-1)=12k+11$$
We conclude we can reach any floor from floor $3$.
Discussion
How could we prove that the sequence $2^m(p-1)+1$ must eventually have a prime of the form $3k+2$ in it? By a Theorem of Landau, we know that integers whose prime factorizations have only primes congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ have density
$$C\frac{x}{\sqrt{\log(x)}}$$
for some constant $C$. That is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{k:k\text{ has prime factors congruent to }1\text{  modulo }3\text{ and }k\leq n\}|\sqrt{\log(n)}}{n}=C$$
Thus, if we could show that the reachable floor from any starting floor $p$ are 'dense' in some sense we could show that eventually we can reach a floor with a prime divisor with the form $3p+2$.

I guess there should be "$2$ is a primitive root of $q$" instead of "$2$ is a primitive root of $2$".

This is long enough to be considered of value.

If I understand correctly, the remaining question in QC_QAOA’s answer is the following: let $n \equiv 1\pmod{3}$ be an odd integer, does one of the integers $2^m(n-1)+1$ (for $m >0$) have a prime divisor $q \equiv 2\pmod{3}$?
(Please tell me if I misunderstood, I will delete this answer.)
The following solution is inspired by the solution to problem N6 of the shortlist of the IMO 2012.
Write $n-1=2^rm$ with $r \ge 1$ and $m$ odd divisible by $3$. Then $m+2$ has an odd prime divisor $q \equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Thus $n-1+2^{r+1}$ is divisible by $q$. Let $t > q+r+1$ be a large integer. Then $2^{t(q-1)-(r+1)}(n-1)+2^{t(q-1)}$ is divisible by $q$. By Fermat’s little theorem, $q \mid 2^{t(q-1)-(r+1)}(n-1)+1$, QED.

Great answer, definitely one of the proofs from the book

Let's reformulate the problem like this:
Let $\{i,f\}\subseteq2\mathbb{N}+1$, $i≠1$ be the initial and final floors, respectively. We call a number sequence $s:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 2\mathbb{N}+1$ an "elevator sequence" if it satisfies the two following conditions:

$s(0)=i$
for every $n$, $s(n+1)=s(n)+a_n-b_n\wedge a_n|s(n)\wedge
   b_n|s(n)$

It can be easily understood that such a sequence can be lawfully followed by the broken elevator if we let the values of $s$ represent the distinct floors, so we might reformulate the prolem as: is there an elevator sequence $s$ and a number $q\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(q)=f$ for any initial and final floors?
Now, lets state the following lemma:
Lemma 3
There is an elevator sequence $s':\mathbb{N}\rightarrow2\mathbb{N}+1$ which satisfies $s'(n+1)=s'(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{b_n}\right)$
Proof:
If $s$ is an elevator sequence, by definition, $a_n|s(n)\wedge b_n|s(n)$, which clearly implies $\frac{s(n)}{a_n}|s(n)\wedge\frac{s(n)}{b_n}|s(n)$. Using these numbers as divisors, we define the subsequence $s'$, which satisfies:
$$s'(n+1)=s'(n)+\frac{s'(n)}{a_n}-\frac{s'(n)}{b_n}=$$
$$s'(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{b_n}\right)$$
Which finishes our proof. $\square$
We use iteratively the proven third lemma to show that there must exist an elevator subsequence that satisfies, for $m>n$:
$$s'(n+m)=s'(n)\prod_{k=n}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k}-\frac{1}{b_k}\right)$$
And, particularly, by defining the sequence:
$$s(n)=iC(n)$$
Where
$$C(n)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1;&n=0\\\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{b_n}\right);&n>0\end{matrix}\right.$$ we get an elevator sequence with the seeked  restrictions (note here that we have to restrict the values of $a_k$ and $b_k$ to avoid $s(n+1)=1$, which can be done by a simple permutation of both values). It remains to show that this sequence can satisfy $f=s(q)=iC(q)$ for some $q$.
For this, note that there is a subsequence satisfiying (from lemma 2 in OP):
$$s'(n+1)=2s'(n)-1$$
Iterating lemma 2 we get a subsequence:
$$s'(n+m)=2^ms'(n)-(m^2-m+1)$$
Let us consider the following:
Hypothesis 1
The following discussions rest on this conjecture:
Let $p>2$ be a prime number such that $p\not| s(n)$ for some $n$. Then, there exists a number $m$ and a subsequence $s'$ that satisfies:
$$s'(n+m)=s'(n)p$$
Thesis: let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ be the natural ring homomorphism that satisfies:
$$x\equiv\phi(x)\mod p$$
Then
$$p|x\Leftrightarrow \phi(x)=0$$
Since $p$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite field, and $\phi$ satisfies:
$$\phi(s'(n+m))=$$
$$\phi(2^ms'(n)-(m^2-m+1))=$$
$$\phi(2^m)\phi(s'(n))-\phi(m^2-m+1)$$
Equating this last expression to $0$, and making the substitution $c=\phi(s'(n))$, we show that:
$$\phi(s'(n+m))=0\Leftrightarrow c\phi(2^m)=\phi(m^2-m+1)$$
Here comes the tricky part: we need to show that such a number $m\in\mathbb{N}$ actually exists for any $c≠0$. I believe a detailed proof can be done from the safety of group theory, but it will enlarge this post unnecessarily. Instead, i'll continue this proof based on a single conjecture, which can be easily tested with a calculator: the sequences $d$ and $d'$, defined by
$$d(k)=c2^k\mod p$$
$$d'(k)=k^2-k+1\mod p$$
are cyclic, with periods $p-1$ (or some divisor of $p-1$) and $p$, respectively, and they share at least one common value. Since one period is prime and the other one is pair, they don't divide each other, and the phases of both cyclic sequences eventually shift, causing their shared value to coincide, proving the existence of the value $m$.
Once proved the existence of $m$, we proved that
$$\phi(s'(n+m))=0$$
And hence, that $p|s'(n+m)$. Also, $$p|s'(n+m)\Leftrightarrow s'(n+m)=pN$$
For some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.
To finish this discussion, we can use the iterated lemma 3 over the number $N$ (note that $p\not| N$)to prove there is a sequence that satisfies
$$s'(n+m)=pN=s'(n)px$$
For some $x\in\mathbb{N}$. Using lemma 1, and the fact that $s'(n)p|s'(n)px$, we get:
$$s'(n+m+1)=s'(n)p$$
We may call $m+1$ just $m$ wlog. $\square$
Having done all the work, we can use these lemmas and the hypotheses to show that we can multiply $i$ with any prime and divide any prime out from the prime decomposition of $i$, and track it down with an elevator sequence; solving the problem with a standard application of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic over $f$.

Apologies, i deleted the answer because hypothesis 1 failed whenever $p|s(n)$, and didn't notice at that moment... However, this case is trivial, and gets easily solved by lemma 1

How did you come to the conclusion $s′(n+m)=2^ms′(n)−(m^2−m+1)$? Iterating Lemma 2 in OP, for $m=4$ you would get $2^4(p-1)+1=16p-15$ while your formula gives $2^4 s-(4^2-4+1)=16s-13$?

Its not an iteration from lemma 2 per se, but rather from the fact that from any number $n$ we can reach the number $2n-1$. After the $m$-th iteration, it is reached the value $2^m-1-\sum_{n:\text{ pair}}^mn$, which can be converted to the given expression with an appropriate polynomial identity.

If you follow the steps in this work, it leads to a definite answer, but here's my adaptation:
Edit: 2
$\textbf{The role of $a_m$ in our proof:}$
The function ( a_m(n) ) is crucial to our proof strategy because it maps the discrete problem of elevator movements to a continuous problem on the complex plane. This allows us to leverage powerful tools from complex analysis and number theory.
Definition and properties of ( a_m(n) ):
Define
$a_m(n) = \frac{m}{2\pi} \arg\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m}\right)$
where ( m ) is an odd integer ( > 1 ) and ( f(n) ) is our elevator function.
Theorem: $a_m(n) \equiv f(n) \pmod{m}$
Proof:

Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/m}$, which is a primitive ( m )-th root of unity. Then:
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m} = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^{f(n) + k}$
We can factor out $\omega^{f(n)}$ from the sum:
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m} = \omega^{f(n)} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^k$

The sum $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^k$ is a geometric series with ( m ) terms and a common ratio ( \omega ):
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^k = \frac{1-\omega^m}{1-\omega}$
Since $\omega^m = e^{2\pi i} = 1$, we have:
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^k = \frac{1-1}{1-\omega} = 0$

To understand the effect of this sum being zero, consider the entire expression $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m}$. Although the series sum is zero, the expression we are considering does not vanish. This is because:
$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m} = m \cdot \omega^{f(n)}$
The factor ( m ) comes from recognizing that we are effectively summing ( m ) identical complex numbers $\omega^{f(n)}$, each multiplied by $e^{2\pi i k/m}$, where ( k ) ranges from 0 to ( m-1 ). The sum of these rotations around the unit circle results in the same direction as ( \omega^{f(n)} ), but with an amplitude scaled by ( m ).

Next, consider the argument of this sum:
$\arg\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m}\right) = \arg(m \cdot \omega^{f(n)}) = \arg(\omega^{f(n)}) = \frac{2\pi f(n)}{m}$
The argument $\arg(m \cdot \omega^{f(n)})$ is simply $\arg(\omega^{f(n)})$, because multiplying a complex number by a positive real number ( m ) does not change its argument—it only scales its magnitude.

Substituting this back into the definition of ( a_m(n) ):
$a_m(n) = \frac{m}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{2\pi f(n)}{m} = f(n)$

Finally, since ( a_m(n) ) is defined modulo ( m ), we have:
$a_m(n) \equiv f(n) \pmod{m}$


This proof shows that $a_m(n) $ precisely corresponds to ( f(n) ) modulo ( m ), leveraging the fact that summing ( m ) identical complex numbers, each a rotation by $2\pi k/m$, scales the magnitude by ( m ) but preserves the argument associated with ( f(n) ). Thus, $a_m(n)$ correctly represents ( f(n) ) modulo ( m ).
where $m$ is an odd integer $> 1$.
$\textbf{Theorem 1:}$ For any odd integers $n > 1$ and $m > 1$, $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^k(n) \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.
$\textit{Proof:}$

Let $G = \{d_1 - d_2 : d_1, d_2 \text{ are divisors of } n\}$. $G$ forms an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

$\exists g \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G = \langle g \rangle$, where $g = \gcd(G)$.

$\forall x \in G, \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \equiv tg \pmod{n}$.

$\therefore \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, f^k(n) \equiv n + t_kg \pmod{n}$ for some $t_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $h = \gcd(g, m)$. $\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ag + bm = h$.

$\therefore \exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_k \equiv a \pmod{m/h}$.

$f^k(n) \equiv n + ag \equiv n + h - bm \equiv n + h \pmod{m}$.

Repeat steps 5-7 $\frac{n-1}{h}$ times to get:
$f^{(\frac{n-1}{h})k}(n) \equiv n + n - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.


$\textbf{Theorem 2:}$ For any odd integers $n, m > 1$, the sequence $\{a_m(f^k(n))\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is dense in $[0, m-1]$.
$\textit{Proof:}$

$a_m(f^k(n)) = \frac{m}{2\pi} \arg\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f^k(n)+j)/m}\right)$

Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/m}$. Then:
$a_m(f^k(n)) = \frac{m}{2\pi} \arg\left(\omega^{f^k(n)} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \omega^j\right)$

$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \omega^j = \frac{1 - \omega^m}{1 - \omega} = 0$

$\therefore a_m(f^k(n)) = \frac{m}{2\pi} \arg\left(\omega^{f^k(n)}\right)$

By Theorem 1, $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists k$ such that $|a_m(f^k(n)) - x| < \varepsilon$ for any $x \in [0, m-1]$.


$\textbf{Theorem 3:}$ From any odd floor $n > 1$, the elevator can reach any other odd floor.
$\textit{Proof:}$

Let $m$ be the target odd floor.

By Theorem 2, $\exists k$ such that $|a_m(f^k(n)) - 1| < \frac{1}{2}$.

This implies $f^k(n) \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.

$\therefore f^k(n) = km + 1$ for some integer $k$, reaching a floor one above a multiple of $m$.

From this floor, we can reach $m$ by going down $km$ floors, which is possible as $km$ is even and thus a difference of two divisors of $km+1$.


Q.E.D.

I'm confused: you say in $2)$ of your $a_m(n)$ proof that $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^k  = 0$ (which I agree with) but then you say in $3)$ that this implies $\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} e^{2\pi i(f(n)+k)/m} =\omega^{f(n)}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \omega^ {k} = m \cdot \omega^{f(n)}$. How did the $0$ become and $m$?

Apologies I didn't add some details before, check above, it doesn't vanish because it's the mod function and $a_m(n)$ is defined around the circle
